# How the SWT is Faster than Swing?

Tags: java, swing, swt

I was exploring the **SWT(Standard Widget Toolkit) API** And I found that it is faster than the **Swing**. Here I have Found some data that comparing the performance between these two

[image]

So I do't undersatnd how it can be faster than Swing.
Anyone who know about it, please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

Swing is implemented totally in Java and runs in the JVM, that makes it independent of the platform (at least in theory) but runs slower than native applications.

SWT is implemented using native libraries and part of it runs natively in the machine, that is why it runs faster; however this makes it platform dependent, you need to know where your application is going to run to download the propper jar and libraries.